# How to postion a new div dynamically below the previous div by calculating its top position from window

Tags: jquery, position

I have to create a div just below an existing div which is position dynamically by using the below jQuery.How to calculate the dynamic top position of my .welcome div and have to create a new .content_txt div just below the .welcome dynamically

Refer [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hQm2r/1/) .I need to get the coming soon text below that welcomer content.

HTML:

```
<div class="welcomer">
    <center>
        <img src="images/sample.png" alt="xxx" class="main-img" />
    </center>
</div>
<div class="content_txt">
    <center>
        <p class="cmg_soon_txt">Coming Soon</p>
    </center>
</div>
```

css:

```
.welcomer {
    width: 100%;
    background: #cc;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).resize(function () {
        $('.welcomer').css({
            position: 'absolute',
                "top": ((($(window).height() - $('.welcomer').outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop() + "px"),
                "left": ((($(window).width() - $('.welcomer').outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft() + "px")
        });
    });
    // To initially run the function:
    $(window).resize();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery UI then you can use [**`position`**](http://jqueryui.com/position/) utility method to align elements relative to another:

```css
.content_txt {
    position: absolute;
}
```

```javascript
$('.content_txt').position({
    my: "center top",
    at: "center bottom",
    of: ".welcomer:first"
});
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/2qymJ/1/)

Comment: can u explain little bit briefly.if i need to position the div- content_txt below the div-welcomer means how i have to write the code.

Comment: For this you simply need to change the `of` parameter.

Comment: We have used jQuery position utility and it has failed in when positioning according to table td elements. So we ended up using javascript solution

Comment: I have edited like this but its not working.$('.content_txt').position({
    my: "center center",
    at: "center center",
    of: welcomer

Comment: can u please implement your concept in this fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/hQm2r/1/).I need to get the coming soon text below that welcomer content.

Comment: I don't see why you find it so difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Here is pure JS solution, this will work. It is modified version of javascript pickaday calendar plugin source.

```
function position(field) {
        var pEl = field,
            viewportWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth,
            viewportHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight,
            scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
            left, top, clientRect;

        if (typeof field.getBoundingClientRect === 'function') {
            clientRect = field.getBoundingClientRect();
            left = clientRect.left + window.pageXOffset;
            top = clientRect.bottom + window.pageYOffset;
        } else {
            left = pEl.offsetLeft;
            top = pEl.offsetTop + pEl.offsetHeight;
            while ((pEl = pEl.offsetParent)) {
                left += pEl.offsetLeft;
                top += pEl.offsetTop;
            }
        }
        return [left, top + field.offsetHeight];
}
position(document.getElementById('elementRef'));
```